# Linux Qt installer framework. How to create installer with dependencies?

Tags: linux, qt, qt-installer

I have Qt project configured by cmake, which uses OpenCV, Qt libs, boost and so one.
How to create installer, which will install those libs during installation?
Or there only variant to put *.so files in packages folder?

If you know how to do it in different way like by creating deb packet please describe it.